# xcode run and debug multiple executables

Tags: xcode, build

I Have a project that has two executables (e.g. client and server) - at the moment, I have to build and run the server and then the client.  I can make it so both client and server are built simultaneously but not run.

How can I set up xcode to run (and debug) both at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to have a debug only section of code which launches the client from the server.  I debug by logging to a common file, with I can tail. You can also attach the debugger to either process by going Debug -> Attach to process...  If anyone has a better solution than this I will be very grateful.